# Fetch xml tag not based on namespace using Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, nodelist

I have this response string as XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns:SRVResponse>
  <ns:Response>
    <ns1:ServiceHeader>
       <ns1:rsHeader>
          <ns1:status>
             <ns1:finStatus>E</ns1:finStatus>
             </ns1:status>
        </ns1:rsHeader>
    </ns1:ServiceHeader>
</ns:Response>
</ns:SRVResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Im trying to fetch this finStatus tag value. This comes as part of ns1, and some times it comes as ns2. So, I dont want to depend on this. I just need to fetch if the tag has finStatus tag.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                           dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
                           DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                           InputSource is = new InputSource();                                 
                            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(strResponse));
                            if(is != null) {
                                Document doc = db.parse(is);                                

                                NodeList idDetails =  doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "status");
                                if(idDetails != null) {
                                    int length = idDetails.getLength();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                                        if (idDetails.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                            Element el = (Element) idDetails.item(i);
                                            if (el.getNodeName().contains("status")) {
                                                status = getElementTextContent(el, "ns1:finStatus");
                                                System.out
                                                        .println("Status :"+status);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

### Method

```
public static String getElementTextContent(Element el, String elemTag) {
    String result = "";
    if(el.getElementsByTagName(elemTag) != null) {
        if(el.getElementsByTagName(elemTag).item(0) != null) {
            if(el.getElementsByTagName(elemTag).item(0).getTextContent() != null) {
                result = el.getElementsByTagName(elemTag).item(0).getTextContent();
            } else {
                result = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is working only because Im passing the tag as ns1:finStatus,

How can I achieve this , not to based on namespace tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are already fetching node without namespace using. So I do not see problem.

2) Use the * search in your second method as well i.e in your getElementTextContent(), use `el.getElementsByTagNameNS("*",elemTag)`.

3) To skip the ns: prefix before passing it to getElementTextContent, Use `getLocalName()` instead of `getNodeName()`

Comment: el.getElementsByTagName("*",elemTag), cannot take two parameters as string.

Comment: sorry, i meant getElementsByTagNameNS

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks Optional

Comment: But I do not see overallStatus in your xml. You can directly fetch this element itself instead of first fetching it's parent. No?

Comment: @Sorry Optional, It was a typo. It should be finStatus. Updated in the question

Comment: you can imporve code a lot. `if (el.getNodeName().contains("status")) ` is not required as you are already getting a node with tag status. Also if status is not a list then you can directly find node by finStatus tag itself. thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156320/discussion-between-yakhoob-and-optional).

Answer (score 1):

Install an XPath 2.0 library and do `//*:finStatus`. Doing this by DOM navigation is just masochism. Either that, or you're being paid for the number of lines of code you write.

Comment: No. I'm here to tell you how to solve your problem, not to do your job for you.

Comment: Thank you @Michael.